# 32-bit and 64-bit different type for Length of dynamic array?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have a DUnitX test suite running fine on Win32. But when I try to compile it for Win64, this line produces a compilation error:

```
Assert.AreEqual(4, Length(r.Values));
```

***[dcc64 Error] ...: E2532 Couldn't infer generic type argument from different argument types for method 'AreEqual'***

r.Values is defined as:

```
Type TIntegers = TArray<Integer>
```

Assert.AreEqual has different overloaded implementations and dcc64 can't choose the right one... ok, but why? And why can dcc32 compile this without a problem?

The only clue I have is that if I hover with the mouse, Delphi will tell me that Length is of type System.Smallint. There is no Assert.AreEqual implementation with Smallint parameters... and sure enough, if I cast it to Integer, dcc64 will compile it.

But this is bugging me a lot. If I look into the System.pas unit I can see that DynArraySetLength takes a NativeInt parameter... a 64 bit integer (I'd expect unsigned, but not sure about that). So why should Length return a 16 bit signed integer? That would seem like trouble waiting to happen, right?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In 64 bit, TArray has a length of type `Int64`. As far as I can tell, there is no `AreEqual` overload for `Int64`, so it tries to use the generic version: `AreEqual<>`. But it looks as if, from the parameters, it can't decide which one.

So in Win64, do:

```
 Assert.AreEqual<Int64>(4, Length(r.Values));
```

or

```
 Assert.AreEqual(4, Integer(Length(r.Values)));
```

The latter is of course the easiest, as it should work in Win32 and Win64, but may not be able to cope with very huge arrays.

---

FWIW, `Length` does not return a `Smallint`. But for functions that differ between platforms, especially "compiler magic" functions like `Length`, such (wrong) information can happen. That is a problem with the IDE, not with the compiler.

### Update:

It may be easier, as @RemyLebeau said, to use `NativeInt` instead. That should work for both Win32 and Win64, as `NativeInt` is `Int32` in Win32 and `Int64` in Win64, and it is also what `_DynArrayLength` returns:

```
Assert.AreEqual<NativeInt>(4, Length(r.Values));
```

Comment: Thanks Rudy. Better to have a bug in the IDE than in the compiler :)
The funny thing is that actually in my test I was comparing the size of an array with the Count of a list implementation, and while the former is platform dependendent, the latter is Integer on all platforms. Now I wonder why lists are limited this way, since they internally use an array to keep elements.
Anyway, I opted for the generic form, which I prefer to the typecast, as it leaves the assertion more readable. I hadn't noticed that overload of AreEqual.

Comment: It is not really an overload. `AreEqual` and `AreEqual<>` are different names that just look similar to us, humans.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I'd just like to add that the generic version AreEqual<Int64> also compiles and works in both Win32 and Win64 (10.1 Berlin, but both generics and Int64 have been in there for a while).

Comment: I would use `Assert.AreEqual<NativeInt>(4, Length(r.Values))` instead. `NativeInt` is `Integer` in 32bit and `Int64` in 64bit. And `System._DynArrayLength()` returns a `NativeInt`.

Comment: @Remy: nice! Rudy: all 3 solutions actually work both on Win32 and Win64. The only doubt that remains is why RTL list, list helper and container interfaces and implementations have not been moved on over to NativeInt. They are internally based on arrays, but all the methods still refer to Integer capacity, count and index parameters :(